# How to search on the basis of all the variable parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a search functionality wherein the user can search on the basis of Id, UserName and status. The data corresponding  to these search filters are in different tables, so I have to put joins on these tables.

Of course user can search on the basis of Id and UserName  or UserName and status and all the combinations that can be considered from these 3 filters.

What I have done is made different functions to address these combinations.

Is there a way that this can be achieved with one method using linq. I am trying to avoid the if-else and switch.

I have already looked into
[Add Conditional Join Dynamically with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533629/add-conditional-join-dynamically-with-linq)
and 
[LINQ - Joins in a dynamic query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850050/linq-joins-in-a-dynamic-query)

This is my code where I am searching on the basis of all the parameters

```
public List<Application> GetApplication(int? applicationId, string userName, string status)
{
     _applicationlist.Clear();
     if (applicationId != 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(status))
     {
         var application = (from a in _targetDbContext.DbSet<ApplicationEntity>()
                           join u in _targetDbContext.DbSet<UserEntity>() on a.InDraftPersonnel equals GetUserID(userName)
                           join v in _targetDbContext.DbSet<ApplicationVersionEntity>() on a.Id equals v.ApplicationId
                           join s in _targetDbContext.DbSet<ApplicationStatusEntity>() on v.VersionStatus equals s.Id
                           where a.Id.Equals(applicationId)
                           where u.UserName.Equals(userName)
                           where s.StatusName.Equals(status)
                           select (new Application
                           {
                               Id = a.Id,
                               AppName = a.AppName,
                               CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy,
                               CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn
                           })).FirstOrDefault();
            _applicationlist.Add(application);

        }
        return _applicationlist;
}
```

The thing is I am not sure if the user would be searching with all the parameters of with just one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove if and try this:

```
where (!applicationid.HasValue || applicationid == 0 || a.Id.Equals(applicationId)) &&
(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || u.UserName.Equals(userName)) &&
(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(status) || s.StatusName.Equals(status))
```

With this where clause all parameters are optional and if one of those is null or empty those parameter don't affect query result and All combination is supported.

Comment: @Rashidi this also retruns null

Comment: If one or more of parametters is null or 0 those parameters dont affect query result. If dont work please check your data or please send your sample data

Comment: @rashidi It seems like it is working fine for 1 condition, but in conjunction its not since I am checking the records on the basis of either/or. So what exactly is  happening is that let say if I search for "Active" status it gives me all the active records but when I search for status and Id (not entering any value) it gives me null. Why ? because there is an "and" condition that checks the records for  status:active and Id:null / Id:any value and I don't have such records in my DB

Comment: Your problem is null applicationid. Check this edited one. This check null value for applicationid

Answer (score 0):

With

```
...
where a.Id.Equals(applicationId) && u.UserName.Equals(userName) && s.StatusName.Equals(status)
...
```

... all parameters must match

---

```
...
where a.Id.Equals(applicationId) || u.UserName.Equals(userName) || s.StatusName.Equals(status)
...
```

... at least one parameter must match.

---

```
...
where a.Id.Equals(applicationId) && u.UserName.Equals(userName) && s.StatusName.Equals(status)
...
```

is equivalent to

```
...
where a.Id.Equals(applicationId)
where u.UserName.Equals(userName)
where s.StatusName.Equals(status)
...
```

See also: [Boolean logical operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

---

Note that you can construct LINQ queries pice-wise.

```
var query = source.Join(..) ...;

if (applicationId.HasValue) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Id == applicationId.Value);
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserName == userName);
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status)) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.StatusName == status);
}
query = query.Select(x => ...);
```

Comment: @Jacot your first suggestion returned null. I think you are checking for either value or for null. That doesn't make the parameters optional. What I am looking for is that if value(s) exist then we query against that value(s) otherwise we make them optional.

Comment: Yes, my last suggestion with the constructed LINQ query does this.

Comment: This is one way of doing it. I think it can be done through expression trees as well.